# GWT + PHP, manage JSON

Tags: php, gwt

I'm trying to connect GWT with a PHP back-end; I successfully loaded some data in the front-end using the provided tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests ; now I'm trying to send data from GWT to PHP using the same piece of code provided, but I don't know how I can modify it. In the Java GWT class I've done

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));
    builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try {
          Request request = builder.sendRequest("{\"data\":\"hello\"}", new RequestCallback() { ...
```

And then in the php script

```
echo json_decode($_POST);
```

But the error is "[INFO] [testapp] -
**Warning**:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\TestApp\TestApp.php** on line **25**"

Can anyone provide a working example of this situation? Or link me some tutorial or document that talk more about how to use GWT with PHP? There is not so much in the official site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo json_decode($HTTP_ROW_POST_DATA);
```

or

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php and http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php (the latter should be preferred)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Because you want to decode your `data` parameter, not all posted parameters.

Comment: it gives me "Undefined index: data" because with sendRequest I can only give a string, not an index: in fact I use this parameter to pass the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

sendRequest takes data and send data as array. you have to use `json_decode(parse_str($_POST['data']))` to receive Request data

Comment: it still gives me 'undefined index:data...' using json_decode(parse_str($_POST['data'])) in backend: maybe the mistake is in 
builder.sendRequest("{\"data\":\"hello\"}", new RequestCallback() { ...

Comment: first u can test which data is coming using **print_R($_POST);**

Comment: ok, u can send parameters like this **builder.sendRequest("?data=hello",.............**

Comment: GWT:
Request request = builder.sendRequest("?data=hello",...
PHP:
echo json_decode(print_r($_POST['data']));
RESPONSE:
>>Undefined index: data

Comment: use **print_r($_POST);**  not echo json_decode(print_r($_POST['data']));